# Angular2 cannot watch when using VSCode

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, angular-cli

I am writing an Angular2 app and use angular-cli with the command `ng serve` to serve the app on localhost. This builds the app and serves it and also **watches** the code for changes.

This works fine and when I make any changes to the code and save, angular-cli detects the changes and rebuilds the code and refreshes the browser.

This works fine in about any editor I use except for VSCode. When making changes to the code and saving the code in VSCode, it saves the code, however, angular-cli does not detect the changes. I have to stop angular-cli from watching and manually do a rebuild.

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 2):

I am working on angular 2 and VSCode for last 6 months and using angular-cli.
but it works fine for me, may be you have some extenstions installed in VSCode which is causing this issue

Comment: This should be comment and not the answer.

Comment: I am using almost no extentions, only the default and a theme. I will play around but so far it has been very weird. As if VSCode is holding the write lock for the files or something.