# Making changes to my app do not get compiled when I refresh my browser window

Tags: angular, visual-studio

Using Visual Studio 2019, and I have created an Angular application from one of the templates (.NET Core application + Angular). I have worked on this project for about a day. Each time I edit something in my code, the app automatically refreshes in my browser (great!).

Until it stopped that is. Now I can make any change I want and the change does not seem to be picked up by the browser. Even if I refresh my browser manually, the changes are not present.
Even stopping my debug session and restarting do not rebuild the app, so nothing changes.

**Things I've tried**:

1. building via the Angular CLI (ng build). This makes no difference either in my debugging browser window. If I refresh the browser, I still see the old version of the app. Even restarting the debugging session still serves the old app. This seems to be cached somewhere, but I can't find where.
2. BUT if I build via Angular CLI and then do "ng serve", I do get an
   up-to-date version of the application, but then I can't debug any c#
   code.
3. I also found someone with a pretty similar problem it seems, but it is related to VS Code. ([Angular2 cannot watch when using VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42360726/angular2-cannot-watch-when-using-vscode)). No solution either
4. Project properties > TypeScript build: "compile on save" is checked. ECMAScript version is ECMASCript 5, "Module System" is empty.

This is my first Angular app (I have always worked with AngularJS), so my knowledge of the CLI or other settings that I need to check are not at quite a good level just yet. I've tried googling for this problem for hours now, and it doesn't seem like anyone has the same problem (or I'm just using the wrong keywords for Googling).

I can demonstrate this just by putting some "hello world" content somewhere. It just won't appear until I do a "ng serve" via the command line.

This used to work just fine and I don't know why it stopped.

Does anyone have any ideas of things I can do or check to alleviate this problem?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Maybe the browser is cashing it? have you tried hard refresh? Does developer console say something maybe?

Comment: @vsarunov I have tried a hard refresh, this is not the problem either. The Developer Console also has no warnings or errors.